# Uncaught ReferenceError: __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_XX__ is not defined

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, arcgis-js-api

We have a custom npm package, `our-map`, we made using TypeScript, webpack, and the ArcGIS JS API to wrap an esri map in a React component. We have confirmed that the module works as intended from a test page within the module. That is, we can display our React Map Component and fetch web maps correctly. The `our-map` npm package is  written to a file share so that we can npm install it into our other applications.

We have `npm install`ed `our-map` to `our-app`, another TypeScript application. We use webpack to bundle the application. However, at runtime we receive the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_61__ is not defined
```

While debugging this in chrome we find the offending module to be

```
module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_61__;

//////////////////
// WEBPACK FOOTER
// external "esri/arcgis/utils"
// module id = 61
// module chunks = 0
```

If we remove the `esri/arcgis/utils` module from `our-map` module and republish, we have a similar error, but, referencing the next esri module.

The code for `our-app` is:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Our Application</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
    <script>
            require(["dist/main.bundle.js"], function (main) {});
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.tsx**
*Simplified for clarity*

```
import * as React from "react";
import {MapContainer} from "our-map";

export const App = (props: IApp) => {
    return <div style={{height: "100%"}}>
        <div style={mapStyle}>
            <MapContainer />
        </div>
    </div>;
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: ['./src/app/main.ts', 'esri', 'esri/map', 'esri/urlUtils', 'esri/geometry/Point', 'esri/arcgis/utils']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'dist/[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            //typescript
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            // css
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            // images
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                query: { mimetype: "image/png" }
            },
            // fonts
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&name=dist/fa/[hash].[ext]&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=dist/fa/[hash].[ext]"
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: [
        function(context, request, callback) {
            if (/^dojo/.test(request) ||
                /^dijit/.test(request) ||
                /^esri/.test(request)
            ) {
                return callback(null, "amd " + request);
            }
            callback();
        }
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Any thoughts as to what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to set `libraryTarget: 'amd'` in the webpack.config.js file like so:

```
output: {
    filename: 'dist/[name].bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'amd'
},
```